# Quit class validator when a property fails URL constraint in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have a field with a url constraint:

```
/**
 * @AppAssert\AccountToMarketer
 */
class Account {

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Url(
     *    protocols = {"https"}
     * )
     */
    private $url;
```

In the class validator "AccountToMarketerValidator" I'm doing the following to leave the rest of the validation and allow NotBlank Constraint to apply

```
if (null === $value->getUrl() || '' === $value->getUrl()) {
    return;
}
```

I would like to know what is the correct syntax for checking that it's not a valid url in order to add the return statement. Something like this:

```
if ($value->getUrl() is not a valid URL) {
    return;
}
```

Otherwise it would be great if there is a way to avoid those return statements. This class has only 2 fields but if I had 10 properties there must be a way to apply properties validation and return the errors and go to the class validation only when all the fields are valid.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html

Comment: @Marleen, thank you for this information. In this case I will need to add a constraint to a method instead of to the whole class. I'll try this.

Comment: There's an example with a custom validator on this page (follow the "example" link all the way at the bottom): https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2947